# Dialog keypress and DOM

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use jQuery's keypress to trigger a button click on a modal dialog created using the jQuery dialog function. The problem is, with the following code, it works the first time around (pressing enter presses the Save button) but I get erratic behavior when I close the modal dialog and reopen it. I'm thinking some variant of `$(this).("button:contains('Save')")` would work, but that doesn't work.

```
$('#dialog').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
      $("button:contains('Save')").click();
        }
});
```

FYI the dialog is opened using a $("#dialog").dialog('open'), not an autoOpen:true.
What would be the best practice for the task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
$('#dialog').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
         var buttons = $(this).dialog('option', 'buttons');
         buttons['Save']();
         e.stopPropagation();
    }
})
```

Comment: It seems to do the job for one dialog, but when "Save" opens a new dialog, everything closes .. the new dialog doesn't have another "Save" button, either...

Comment: The keyup event handler will not be detached from the element unless you remove the element from the DOM.  Sounds like you have another problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

keypress is for letters. keydown is for everything. I would try using keydown.

Your code most likely does not execute. Enter will trigger the default action so that's why it works the first time.

More info here:

http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/KeyPress-KeyDown-KeyUp-The-Difference-Between-Javascript-Key-Events.aspx

Comment: Actually, you're partially right. If the dialog contains a form, pressing enter "submits" it, but Ken's response helps when the dialog doesn't contain a form, because then pressing enter doesn't do anything.