# jQuery Dialog does not respond to keyboard press

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-ui

I have  a jQuery confirmation dialog that does not fire the event associated with the default button when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>; when I use the mouse, the button behaves as expected.

The default button ('Cancel') **does** highlight when I press enter, but nothing else happens.

This is the dialog:

[image]

And here is the code that produces the above dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#m_btnNext').click(function (e) {
            var my_messages = 'warning';
            if (my_messages.length > 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#dialog-confirm-withdraw').html(my_messages);
                $("#dialog-confirm-withdraw").dialog("open");
                return false;
            }
            return true;    
            });

        var cascadeConfirmWithdrawMarkup = "<div id='dialog-confirm-withdraw' title='Withdraw'><p>Set on build</p></div>";
        $(cascadeConfirmWithdrawMarkup).appendTo('body').hide();

        $('#dialog-confirm-withdraw').dialog({ title: '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Withdraw Warnings',
            width: 400,
            height: 175,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function () {
                $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq(1)').focus();
            },
            buttons: {
                "Proceed with withdraw": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
});
```

In its simplest form, [this code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/gRP3P/2/), but I am having tremendous difficulty pinpointing the culprit in my *real* form.

I commented out all other javascript so only the above code exists; no errors are logged to the console; yet nothing happens.

If there's not an obvious error in my js above, what is the best way to find the needle in this haystack?

Masochists can download the full html page (with all javascript), [here](http://www.o1solution.com/WithdrawForm.zip).  I used FF's Save As "Web Page, Complete" to create that zip.

Bear in mind that I am only adding functionality to this form; I did not create it.

Comment: On your *real* form, is the cancel button definitely focused on when you press enter? You mention highlighting, but just want to double check. You can press tab to toggle through form fields on your browser to test this as you no doubt know already.

Comment: Do you have any keypress events attached to the document?

Comment: We need to see what other events you have in your real form. Please post the whole code.

Comment: @martinwnet yes.  The form loads with the cancel button highlighted.  Tabbing to _Proceed with withdraw_ and pressing enter does nothing as well.   Tabbing to the "X" and pressing enter, however, closes the form.

Comment: @epascarello  As far as I could tell, no.  I found a couple of SO examples of attaching KeyPress and KeyDown events [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466726/how-to-intercept-jquery-dialog-esc-key-event) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539758/dialog-keypress-and-dom) (See Ken Browning's answer), but I could not get a response using them).  In all fariness, I could not get them working even in the examples so I was more than likely missing something.

Comment: @castillo.io posted...but beware...it is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Can you add the HTML as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In halcyonCommon.js you have a function called KeyListener() which is called on document load.  That function adds an event listener for keydown, and it appears to be handling escape and enter keydown events for your whole document:

```
        case KeyCode.Enter:             
            if (el.tagName == "INPUT") {                    
                switch (el.type) {
                    case "checkbox" :
                    case "password" :
                    case "radio" :
                    case "text" : 
                        {   //Check for datebox and timebox, has controller --> onblur before click OK
                            if (el.Controller && el.Controller.onblur)
                                el.Controller.onblur({target : el});

                            return oThis.clickAction(oThis._DefaultButton, e); 
                        }
                    break;                      
                    case "file" ://ThamHNguyen, added 14-NOV-06
                        return oThis.clickAction(oThis._DefaultButton, e);
                        break;

                    default:
                        return true;
                }
            } else if (el.tagName == "SELECT") {
                return oThis.clickAction(oThis._DefaultButton, e);              
            } else if (el.tagName == "HTML" || el.tagName == "BODY" || el.tagName == "TD") { //"TD" : on IE only
                return oThis.clickAction(oThis._DefaultButton, e);              
            } else if (el.tagName == "TEXTAREA" || el.tagName == "A" ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false; //Prevent default button of IE
            }
```

See the last else case?  Removing that solves the problem, but it's possible that this will cause undesired behavior elsewhere in your program.  If it does, you'll need to add a third possible occasion for returning true (and therefore allowing normal behavior) in this line:

```
} else if (el.tagName == "TEXTAREA" || el.tagName == "A" )
```

For example:

```
} else if (el.tagName == "TEXTAREA" || el.tagName == "A" || el.tagName == "SPAN" )
```

...though that may not be specific enough.